# How to set default value of a slot as NULL in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm new to R.

I'm trying to define a class similar to a tree node, that is , it has a left node and right node, which should be of the same class as the parent node. So I define the class as follows:

```
setClass('Node', representation=(left='Node',right='Node', ...))
```

I want to set the default value of Node to be NULL by setting a prototype, but R says the following:

```
  invalid class "Node" object: invalid object for slot "left" in class "bicluster": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "Node"
```

But if I don't speficy the default value to be NULL, then the default value will be a recursive Node of depth 4, which I think is some waste of resource.

Is my consideration unnecessary or is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a revised answer.

Class unions are funky -- they effectively insert a class into the middle of an existing hierarchy, so suddenly things that extend `list` now extend `listOrNULL`.

Instead I'd create a small class hierarchy that represents a "Tree" that can either be "Empty" or "Internal". The "Internal" class will have a slot to contain data (of type "ANY"), plus the left and right links, which will be "Tree" elements.

```
setClass("Tree")

setClass("Empty", contains="Tree")

setClass("Internal", contains="Tree",
         representation=representation(elem="ANY", left="Tree", right="Tree"),
         prototype=prototype(left=new("Empty"), right=new("Empty")))
```

I'll write a constructor for my Tree, with methods for creating an empty tree, and a tree from an element plus left and right descendants.

```
setGeneric("Tree", function(elem, left, right) standardGeneric("Tree"),
           signature="elem")

setMethod(Tree, "missing", function(elem, left, right) new("Empty"))

setMethod(Tree, "ANY", function(elem, left, right) {
    new("Internal", elem=elem, left=left, right=right)
})
```

A basic operation is to insert an element `x` into a tree `t`

```
setGeneric("insert", function(x, t) standardGeneric("insert"))

setMethod(insert, c("ANY", "Empty"), function(x, t) {
    Tree(x, Tree(), Tree())
})

setMethod(insert, c("ANY", "Internal"), function(x, t) {
    if (x < t@elem) {
        l <- insert(x, t@left)
        r <- t@right
    } else {
        l <- t@left
        r <- insert(x, t@right)
    }
    Tree(t@elem, l, r)
})
```

Another operation is to test for membership

```
setGeneric("member", function(x, t) standardGeneric("member"))

setMethod(member, c("ANY", "Empty"), function(x, t) FALSE)

setMethod(member, c("ANY", "Internal"), function(x, t) {
    if (x < t@elem) member(x, t@left)
    else if (t@elem < x) member(x, t@right)
    else TRUE
})
```

An interesting, functional, property of this implementation is that it is persistent

```
> t <- Tree()
> t1 <- insert(10, t)
> t2 <- insert(5, t1)
> t3 <- insert(7, t2)
> t4 <- insert(15, t3)
> which(sapply(1:20, member, t4))
[1]  5  7 10 15
> which(sapply(1:20, member, t2))
[1]  5 10
```

This is not going to be efficient when there are a lot of updates, because of the inefficiencies of S4 class creation and because modifying a tree (e.g., adding a node) copies all nodes in the path to the new node. A [different approach](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e12/help/10/10/0519.html) represents the tree as a `matrix` of left, right, value triples. The S4 implementation would still have poor performance, because the updates of the instance would create new instances, duplicating everything. So I'd end up at a reference class, with fields 'value' (a vector of whatever the tree is supposed to hold and a `matrix` of left and right relations.

Answer (score 9):

At one time you needed to use `setClassUnion("listOrNULL",members=c("list", "NULL"))` to get a NULL into a slot that was defined as a list. I think that is now an available class. Cannot test while your setup incomplete, but defining a super-class "NodeOrNull" may get you past your initial barrier.

Comment: This is the approach recommended by Chambers in Software for Data Analysis (+1)

Comment: Usually in these matters you should pay more attention to @MartinMorgan. He knows what he is doing. I'm a hacker.